# Turn off term labels in candisc plot

Tags: r, plot

Does anyone know how to turn off the term labels that a appear on a multivariate plot via the candisc r package? Here is an example plot:

[image]

Note the CLR, BAL_OC and YAM_OC term labels, I would like to remove these and use a legend (which I have already coded but not shown). I used the following code:

```
plot(sc, term = "Estuary", col=c("chartreuse", "blue4", 
"aquamarine3", "coral", "brown", 'burlywood2', "cadetblue", "black", 
"azure3", "chocolate", "blueviolet"), pch=c(0,1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 
,6,7,8,9,10,11))
legend(-10, 2, c('Bal_Oc', 'CLR', 'GGR', 'HKR', 'HUR', 'MLR', 'MNR', 
'PST', 'RMR', 'SHR', 'Yam_Oc'), pch=c(pch=c(0,1, 2, 3, 4 
,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)), title="Estuary", col=c("chartreuse", "blue4", 
"aquamarine3", "coral", "brown", 'burlywood2', "cadetblue", "black", 
"azure3", "chocolate", "blueviolet"))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you think of reducing the effort of people who love helping others by providing a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), you'll most likely get a response in less than an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined that the term labels are hard coded and therefore cannot be manipulated.